# What cable do I use to connect my generator to my panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, usa

What is the type of cable I should use for electrical panels for generator sets in the United States?

If I am not wrong, the American standard for this kind of cable should be rated 600 volts or less. Am I correct?

Comment: Almost all power cables and insulated wire will be 600v there are lower voltage types out there. We need to meet code, are you talking about the wiring inside your walls? Or the flexible cord that connects to the generator itself ?

Comment: I've edited the title of your question to actually ask a question (as is requested here). Please ensure that it's actually asking the question _you_ intended to ask. If not, please [edit] it again to be accurate and to clarify your question. TBH, your first sentence isn't really clear...

Comment: Actually, it would 600V or **more**. More is fine. Less is where there is a problem. You technically (US) only need 250V protection, but code might require 600V (I have no idea) and that seems to be the standard. Because it is what most people need (higher voltage is generally for electrical rooms in big buildings that get higher voltage from the utility and lower the voltage on-site) higher levels (which are 100% OK) generally cost a lot more.

Comment: All mains-rated wiring in North America is rated for 600V until you get into Medium Voltage stuff, which is *waaaaay* out of scope for DIY.SE.  Can you tell us if this is a direct buried run, a cord to a portable generator, something to go in a conduit out to the generator pad, or something inside your house connected to a generator circuit?